# Limit of matrix existence for values of x and y

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have been given this question to answer

The Matrix$$C = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 7 & 1 & 3 \\
7 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
1&1&7&3 \\
 3 &3 &3&3
\end{pmatrix} $$

has eigenvalues: $12 ,-6, 6, 0$

$N(x,y) = xC+yI_{4}$

depending on $x$ and $y$ determine when $\lim_{k\to \infty}N(x,y)^{k}$ exists, sketch the region for $x$ and $y$

Attempt:

From class I have the following theorem

> Let A be an $n$ x $n$ matrix. Then $\lim_{k\to \infty}A^{k}$exists if and only if
>
> $A$ has no eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|{\lambda}| \geq1$
>
> If $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $\lambda = 1$, then all block of Jordan Canonical for $J(A)$ of the form $J_{k}(1)$ must have $k=1$

Using this theorem and the eigenvalues provided my attempt would be to find the region for $x$ and $y$ such that

$$|12x+y|\leq1$$
$$|-6x+y|\leq1$$
$$|6x+y|\leq1$$
$$|0x+y|\leq1$$

However I'm finding defining the region difficult so I'm uncertain if this is the correct approach

Comment: To be changed into "$A$  has no eigenvalue λ with $|λ| \geq 1$" (not $<$)

Comment: fixed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is right, with the exception that you cannot allow the eigenvalue $-1$. So you are looking at 
\begin{align}
-1&<12x+y\leq 1\\
-1&<-6x+y\leq 1\\
-1&<6x+y\leq 1\\
-1&<y\leq 1\\
\end{align}
So basically you need to plot eight lines and look at the region they enclose. Lazy people like me use some [graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6iy9ihtuku) and then Paint:

[image]

If you want to express this analytically you will have look at the four lines that define the green region. Then you can tell that your region is given by those $x,y$ with 
\begin{align}
-6x+y\leq1 \\ 
12x+y\leq1\\
12x+y>-1\\
-6x+y>-1
\end{align}
and we can summarize this as 
\begin{align}
-1<-6x+y\leq1\\
-1<12x+y\leq 1
\end{align}